# Alert messages show my logic is correct but Google Chrome's html output viewer shows different

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am making a `form` for a website that allows a person to enter their information in `input` tags to register, so I need information (i.e. name, address, age). I also want a button, at the bottom of the screen, to be able to make an **AJAX** request to bring all the same `input` elements in again, so the user can register another person without going to another page.
I am doing this in one `form`, so I need each `input` to have an unique name, so that when I access the information on the server side I can get it.

So here is my code:

```
<div id="registrationfield">
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last" name="last0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="gender0" >
            <option></option>
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="emailregistration" name="email0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip0" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>T-Shirt Size</label>
    <select id="tshirt" name="tshirt0" >
        <option>S</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>L</option>
        <option>XL</option>
        <option>XXL</option>
    </select>
    <button id="moreregistration">More</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the HTML I am bringing in with the **AJAX** request:

```
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="age"/>
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="gender">
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text"  name="city" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" />
</div>
<div class="registerfield">
    <label>T-Shirt Size</label>
    <select name="tshirt" >
        <option>S</option>
        <option>M</option>
        <option>L</option>
        <option>XL</option>
        <option>XXL</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And what I do, once I load the HTML inside my main HTML document, is to change the `name` attribute of every `input` and `select` element to have an additional number on the end.
For example when the first AJAX request is made, it makes `name="first"` to `name="first1"`, and for each time the request is made, that number increments by one.

Now in my **JavaScript** I made alerts to make sure that every element's attribute is being set like it should, and from the alerts I am getting it SEEMS correct.

However, I looked at the source code in **Google Chrome** and the `name` attributes are very incorrect.  I have no idea what the issue could be. Here is my **jQuery**, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //this is the variable that will be added on to the end of the form attribute
    var counter = 1;



    $('#moreregistration').click(function () {

        $.get("registerform.html", function (data) {
            $(data).appendTo('#registrationfield').hide().fadeIn();
        }).complete(function () {


            //this variable sets my index so I do not effect the input elements already in the html.
            var formElementIndexToInsert = (counter * 10);


            //loop through all elements for a single ajax request
            for (var j = formElementIndexToInsert; j <= formElementIndexToInsert + 9; j++) {

                alert(j);

                if ((j % 10 == 3) || (j % 10 == 9)) {


                    var formName = $('.registerfield').eq(j).children('select').attr('name');
                    formName = (formName + counter);
                    alert(formName);
                    $('.registerfield').eq(j).children('select').attr('name', formName);

                } else {
                    var formName = $('.registerfield').eq(j).children('input').attr('name');
                    formName = (formName + counter);
                    alert(formName);
                    $('.registerfield').eq(formElementIndexToInsert).children('input').attr('name', formName);

                }



            }
            counter++;
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake.  In my if-else statement the last line in the else the phrase 'formElementIndexToInsert' needs to be 'j'